# Avoiding concurrency of Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, concurrency

I have following scenraio:

I need to fire updating procedures in fixed time intervals. But some of the procedure might take longer than the interval. I want to avoid stacking calls to procedures (in case one want to start before its previous execution hasn't been finished).

My colleague advised me to create in database additional table with two columns:
one with name of procedures and `IsActive` column (`bit`). So, before executing any procedure, I check the corresponding value of `IsActive`. If it's `1`, then abort execution.

Now, the problem:

when I get to execution, I need to set the value of `IsActive` to `1` for the procedure, which I try to do like this:

```
UPDATE ProcActivity SET IsActive = 1 WHERE ProcedureName = 'proc_name'
EXEC proc_name
UPDATE ProcActivity SET IsActive = 0 WHERE ProcedureName = 'proc_name'
```

But, SQL is executing batches, so the value of `1` isn't visible (the `UPDATE` isn't commited) until the procedure is finished.

So, how to commit this `UPDATE`? I tried with `COMMIT`, but didn't work... I can't use `GO`, because it's wrapped in `IF` statement...

Comment: Use a `commit` after the `update`.

Comment: That didn't work. I have tried in this order `update... commit exec... update...`

Comment: It's a niche feature, but this may actually be a good (well, decent) use case for [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use transactions this way because of visibility, unless you want to use extra hints. WHich I would not do personally.

If you want "only one stored proc execution current" then I would consider `sp_getapplock` and `sp_releaseapplock` in the stored procedure.

This will enforce force "single threaded" execution.

[Other questions here that show how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sp_getapplock)

And, to abort other calls, set the `@LockTimeout=0`, so if the result code is different from zero, then you know that you need to abort current call.

Comment: So I tried this:
`EXEC sp_getapplock @DbPrincipal = 'dbo', @Resource = '[dbo].[proc_name]', @LockMode = 'Shared'; ` and it didn't prohibited me from executing procdure...

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: that would be because a shared lock can be *shared*. Take an exclusive lock.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: from different sessions/transactions, only one can take an exclusive lock, while the other one waits. I've just verified that actually works. If you're getting the lock, then there's no other session/transaction active (locks are automatically released when the session/transaction ends, depending on the `@LockOwner`.

Comment: Anyway, if other calls have to wait, that is what I am trying to avoid. I want to abort the call to the procedure, not to wait with execution.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: that's what `@LockTimeout` and the result code are for.