# Unexpected, non-intuitive behavior of BEGIN - COMMIT TRANSACTION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, commit

I'm writing in reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034358/avoiding-concurrency-of-stored-procedures) of mine asked couple of days ago.

The answer which suit my needs was that:

```
UPDATE ProcActivity SET IsActive = 1 WHERE ProcedureName = 'proc_name'
BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC proc_name
COMMIT TRANSACTION
UPDATE ProcActivity SET IsActive = 0 WHERE ProcedureName = 'proc_name'
```

Now here's another qustion:

intuitively, I thought if I wrap `UPDATE` statement in `BEGIN....COMMIT TRANSACTION` it would take effect as soon as it reaches `COMMIT...`, but I was wrong. Actually, when you do it like stated above, then when it reaches `BEGIN...`, then update take place.

To sum up:

Doing update like this:

```
UPDATE ProcActivity SET IsActive = 1 WHERE ProcedureName = 'proc_name'
BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC proc_name
COMMIT TRANSACTION
UPDATE ProcActivity SET IsActive = 0 WHERE ProcedureName = 'proc_name'
```

cuases that, the value of the `IsActive` is set to one during execution of procedure `proc_name` (update took effect before procedure started).

Doing update like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE ProcActivity SET IsActive = 1 WHERE ProcedureName = 'proc_name'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
EXEC proc_name
UPDATE ProcActivity SET IsActive = 0 WHERE ProcedureName = 'proc_name'
```

will have no effect during execution of `proc_name`. The value of `IsActive` is set to 0 during execution of the procedure.

Why is it working like that? What's the mechanism behind it?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue - in both cases you I get `0` - `1` - `0`:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[StackOoverFlow]') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[StackOoverFlow];
END;

IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow]') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow];
END;

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackOoverFlow]
(
    [ProcedureName] SYSNAME
   ,[IsActive] BIT
); 

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow] AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [IsActive]
    FROM [dbo].[StackOoverFlow]
    WHERE [ProcedureName] = '[dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow]';
END;

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOoverFlow] ([ProcedureName], [IsActive])
VALUES ('[dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow]', 0);

GO

SELECT [IsActive]
FROM [dbo].[StackOoverFlow]
WHERE [ProcedureName] = '[dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow]';

BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE [dbo].[StackOoverFlow]
SET [IsActive] = 1
WHERE [ProcedureName] = '[dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow]'; 

COMMIT TRANSACTION

EXEC [dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow];

UPDATE [dbo].[StackOoverFlow]
SET [IsActive] = 0
WHERE [ProcedureName] = '[dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow]'; 

SELECT [IsActive]
FROM [dbo].[StackOoverFlow]
WHERE [ProcedureName] = '[dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow]';


GO

SELECT [IsActive]
FROM [dbo].[StackOoverFlow]
WHERE [ProcedureName] = '[dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow]';

UPDATE [dbo].[StackOoverFlow]
SET [IsActive] = 1
WHERE [ProcedureName] = '[dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow]'; 

BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC [dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow];
COMMIT TRANSACTION

UPDATE [dbo].[StackOoverFlow]
SET [IsActive] = 0
WHERE [ProcedureName] = '[dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow]'; 

SELECT [IsActive]
FROM [dbo].[StackOoverFlow]
WHERE [ProcedureName] = '[dbo].[usp_StackOoverFlow]';
```

Comment: So, both codes have exactly same effect? And so first code works as I supposed?

Comment: You can try this code on your SQL Server. In my working environment it is same. If it not the same on yours, you can show the SP body first.